# Should friend functions necessarily take const objects as their arguments?

Tags: c++

I guess it's mandatory for a friend function to have the objects of the classes it is a friend of as its arguments, but is it allowed to modify those objects?

Comment: There are no particular requirements on what parameters, if any, a friend function must take, or what it should or may do with them. Wherever did you get this idea that something about them is "mandatory"?

Comment: `but is it allowed to modify those objects`, yes it is, that's the point of it

Comment: If it was mandatory, it wouldn't compile otherwise, most probably. Same with *necessary*. If something is allowed, there usually (very very probably) is a good use-case for it. There not much overlooked things in standard.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't accept the object of the class as argument, how can it access it's private members???

Comment: The function can retrieve the object it's interested in from elsewhere.

Comment: @Grendan Who says it must access private members? It's probably pointless to declare a friend function that doesn't, but that doesn't mean it's illegal to do so.

Comment: @Praetorian Well, friend function needs to be able to access private members, that is the definition. But it doesn't need to make use of this privilege at all. *Edit:* You changed the modal, now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: As possible try to avoid the use of friend functions. It breaks the OOP design.

Comment: I know we don't have to, but if we were to make the instance of the class (the function is a friend of) passed to the friend function, a constant, does it have to be declared with a keyword const in both the argument list in the friend function prototype inside the class A as well as the friend function definition outside it or just the former will do?

Answer (score 3):

It's not mandatory at all. There is no requirement whatsoever. The only difference is that a `friend` function *may* access the private members of a class. But it could be totally unrelated.

```
class A {
    int x;

    friend void foo();
};


void foo() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

`foo` takes no args, and doesn't even reference `A` in any way, but it's still a `friend` and that is completely allowed. Pointless, but perfectly legal.

We could have it do something like this instead:

```
void foo() {
    A a;
    a.x = 42;
}
```

Comment: Yes, pointless is the word. In this example, the friend function cannot access the private members of A and the only way for that to happen is to pass an instance of A as the argument to foo, correct?

Comment: @Grendan, No, it could use a global, etc. (which I wouldn't recommend), but it could also make a local `A`.

Comment: Well, yeah, it is pointless to declare a function as a friend that does not need to access any private/protected members of a class.  But there is nothing stopping foo() creating an instance of A - even if all A's constructors are private, accessing its private members.   There is also nothing stopping foo() from accessing private static members of A.

Comment: Awesome perspective. One last question about this topic: If we were to make the instance of A (if) passed to foo, a constant, does it have to be declared with a keyword const in the argument list both in the friend function prototype inside the class A as well as the friend function definition outside it or just the former will do?

Comment: I know we don't have to, but if we were to make the instance of the class (the function is a friend of) passed to the friend function, a constant, does it have to be declared with a keyword const in both the argument list in the friend function prototype inside the class A as well as the friend function definition outside it or just the former will do?

Comment: @Grendan, Top level `const` on function parameters is ignored. Better to leave it out of declarations since it's an implementation detail.

Comment: Woah...I didn't know that. If a member function is to take a constant argument, can I just ignore the const keyword in the function declaration in the class definition and only include it when it is defined outside the class?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but I believe by top level, you mean function prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Friendship grants access to all private members of a class.

That includes ability to modify any or all (protected, private, public) members of a non-const object, ability to modify any or all mutable members of a const object.   It also includes ability to read the value of any or all members.

This assumes the members themselves also permit the operations.

Comment: I know we don't have to, but if we were to make the instance of the class (the function is a friend of) passed to the friend function, a constant, does it have to be declared with a keyword const in both the argument list in the friend function prototype inside the class A as well as the friend function definition outside it or just the former will do?